# Is there a puzzle that is only solvable by assuming there is a unique solution?

Tags: grid-deduction, puzzle-creation, solvability

Is it possible to construct a puzzle that is:

1. Solvable if you assume there is a single unique solution
2. Not solvable if you do not make this assumption

My intuition says that the answer is "No", but I'm struggling to prove it one way or another.

By "puzzle" I mean:

- Something that is (typically) solvable by using logical steps, no guessing required.
- Does not have to be perfect-knowledge (e.g. minesweeper puzzles allowed)
- Does not have to conform to a 2D grid.  I'm pretty sure that all logical puzzles can be mapped to an n-D grid, however.

Comment: Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49557/is-ambiguity-prevention-sufficient-reason-to-infer-a-clue

Comment: I find this question very interesting!
Maybe this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_impossible_puzzles

Comment: It seems like this question is meant to be about what we call [grid-deduction] puzzles, so I've edited that tag in -- if that's not accurate, feel free to edit it back out.

Comment: @Deusovi, maybe I'm wrong but I feel this question is more a question about meta on puzzles and does have little with `grid-deduction` tag.

Comment: Yeah, grid deduction isn't really what I'm going for.  It's most often applied to those kinds of puzzles, but isn't specific to it.  Maybe something like "logic-puzzles"?  Dunno.

Comment: Oh, what other types of puzzles are you talking about then? I think a sufficiently broad definition of [grid-deduction] would cover most cases that 'uniqueness' matters, and solvability through logical deduction is important. (If you're not talking about solvability as in "a deductive path from the puzzle to the solution", and you just mean "the ability to get to the solution", then it's an even easier 'no' answer: people can just intuit their way to the solution.)

Comment: Essentially, I'm going for "Puzzle that can be solved logically without guessing".  However, another assumption that I should have made clearer is that it doesn't have to be a perfect-knowledge puzzle.  For example, minesweeper is a game that (if constructed properly) can be solved without guessing but also doesn't provide all information up front.

I'll edit my question to make this clearer, but if you have better tags, that'd be great

Comment: "The three cards in this stack alternate between aces and kings. Pick an ace."

Comment: Yes, but I read it so long ago I remember only that it existed.

I think this belongs not to Puzzling, as such, but to some of number theory.

Comment: Yes. There is one such puzzle.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At least not if the solution space is a [countable infinite set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set), or smaller.

In that case, we can compute the finite time person 2) will need to find the solution found by person 1) by enumeration, making the strategy of 2) a computable function and therefore violating the constraints of the question.

---

Response to edit:

The "does not have to be perfect-knowledge" point changes things up a bit. It allows puzzles of the following type:

"I have a hidden number that's either 3 or 4. Give me two natural numbers that sum to my hidden number".

1. Assuming a unique solution, we can rule out that the number is 4 since both 1+3 and 2+2 would be valid solutions, making them not unique. We have now logically deduced that the solution is 1+2. (The deduction would be "iff 1+3 is a valid solution, so is 2+2. But since this puzzle has a unique solution, that can not be the solution".)
2. Not assuming that the solution is unique, we can not rule out that the hidden number is 4. The puzzle can thus not be solved without guessing.

Allowing imperfect-knowledge puzzles thus leads to the opposite conclusion, that such puzzles are indeed possible.

---

A discussion later:

An interesting fact to point out is that if one assumes a unique solution to the puzzle above, one may arrive at different conclusions by attacking it with different unique arguments. One such argument could be "if one addend is 3, 1+3 = 4 is a unique solution to the puzzle, so that's the solution". What this does is implicitly allow the puzzle to have multiple solutions, making a unique argument allowed to pick *any* (or none) of the solutions.

This does not change much in that 1) will find a solution while 2) will not, but it is a different and incompatible interpretation of the puzzle. Nevertheless, it still says that the answer to the question is "yes, such puzzles are possible".

For a more rigorous proof that avoids multiple interpretations like this, one must have clear definitions of what exactly "solve" means, and how "hidden information" works.

Comment: Oooh, good counter example.  Thanks :)

Comment: I'm no longer convinced that this works anymore.  Consider it a different way:  If we assume a unique solution, we can rule out that the addends do not include a "1":  If one of them was a 1, the other addend could either be a 2 or a 3, making it not unique.  So, the answer must be 2,2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116190/discussion-between-nathan-merrill-and-se-stop-firing-the-good-guys).

Comment: I guess this assumes that a solution can be validated by a computable function? Maybe for the puzzles we care about, a valid solution should be self-evident. Or, if we say a solution includes a proof of correctness (and is hence self-evident), then a proof by person 1 might use the assumption of uniqueness and person 2 would reject this proof. Another proof might (or might not) exist that doesn't use this assumption but we don't know if/when person 2 will find it by enumeration.

Answer (score 11):

No.

If there is **exactly one** way to fill out the grid in a valid way, then that can be found without using any logic based on uniqueness. (It may be very painful, and require brute-forcing a lot, but it won't be *impossible to find*.)

If there are **exactly two** valid ways to fill out the grid, then uniqueness logic cannot help you. You can never make a deduction of the form "if X happens, then there are multiple solutions, so it can't be X" that rules out *exactly one* of the two solutions -- because all deductions of that form must rule out the multiple solutions including X!

If there are **three or more** valid ways to fill out the grid, uniqueness logic can give you any of them! In the extreme case, you can enumerate all possible solutions, and say: "It's either solution #7, or it's not solution #7. If it's not #7, then there are multiple solutions. Therefore it's solution #7."

So, no matter what, you can't make a puzzle solvable with only uniqueness logic. You might be able to make one that's *easier* with uniqueness logic, but not one that's *only possible* with it.

---

Of course, you may not be convinced by my last case there -- it seems very artificial. There are more natural examples that demonstrate the problem, though.

The paper ["Uniqueness in Logic Puzzles"](http://gapdjournal.com/style/gapd-sample.pdf) has a good explanation of why this is, and they give a particularly good example of how uniqueness logic can go wrong when there are multiple solutions. They give this Slitherlink puzzle, that has exactly three possible solutions:

> [image]

And then show that, depending on where you check for uniqueness, you'll get to a different solution. If you check a segment near the top left, you'll find that solution (c) is 'the correct one'; if you check a segment near the bottom right, you'll find that solution (b) is 'the correct one'.

> [image]

This is a relatively trivial example, but this could be embedded as one corner in a larger puzzle (with the loop escaping in the bottom right rather than wrapping around). If it was embedded like that, an experienced Slitherlink solver could very easily notice one of those. And if they used uniqueness logic, they would get either solution (b) or (c) without ever realizing something was wrong.

---

It may be possible to have only one "natural" solution if you assume uniqueness: that is, a "natural" set of uniqueness deductions will lead to only one of the solutions. But now we've left the realm of pure logic, and you're looking for something that will be "natural" to *every single solver* -- this would be very subjective, and unlikely to work for all but the most trivial examples.

Comment: "In the extreme case, you can enumerate all possible solutions". For slitherlink, and many other grid deduction puzzles, yes. For grid deduction puzzles filling in real numbers in boxes, no.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys I'm not familiar with any [grid-deduction] puzzles that allow arbitrary real numbers. If you know of any that *do* allow arbitrary real numbers (which can't immediately be whittled down to a countable set of numbers, and still have unique solutions), I'd be interested to hear about them!

Comment: Here's a very boring one: Pick a function $f$ that maps two real numbers to a real number. On a grid with the clues being a real number for each row and column, fill in the grid such that cell_ij = f(rowClue_i,columnClue_j). (This puzzle does not qualify for OPs question though).

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys Hm, fair enough. (Though I may argue that you can limit things to the computable reals -- it seems to me that if the solution has to be checked for correctness by an algorithm, the only allowable involved numbers would be the computable reals. And there are countably many of those.)

Comment: I see your point. The example puzzle must then use an incomputable function, and since the [usual example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) has the unfortunate property of being an integer function, I've run out of counterexamples.

Comment: One may have a constraint that specifies some transform T such that if s is a solution to puzzle p, T(s) will be a solution to T(p), and specifies that not only must any correct solution x satisfy all other constraints, but T(x) must either equal x or violate at least one other constraint.  Such a constraint in e.g. a Sudoku would allow legitimate exploitation of Gurth's Theorem to avoid the need to consider non-symmetric solutions to symmetric puzzles.

Comment: One could also specify that e.g. a correct solution to a particular Sudoku will be free of 2x2 deadly patterns.  Adopting such a constraint would mean that a potential possible solution which would force a 2x2 deadly pattern could be safely regarded as incorrect; while it would yield two or more in the absence of the deadly-pattern constraint, such a constraint would exclude all of them.

Comment: @supercat Yes, but that's an additional constraint on the *solution*, not a "uniqueness" constraint on puzzle construction. It happens to look like a uniqueness deduction on a regular Sudoku puzzle, but this would be a variant rule added to the ruleset, so you'd still be making deductions solely from the rules.

Comment: @Deusovi: Indeed, but such a constraint is very similar to a "uniqueness constraint", and could allow some puzzles to have more elegant solutions than would otherwise be possible.  It's possible to have a puzzle where an assumption that a solution is unique may make it practical to exclude from consideration non-solutions that would otherwise only be ruled out by a long, boring, and inelegant exhaustive search.

Comment: @Deusovi: On the flip side, a puzzle could specify a disambiguation rule which for 2x2 deadly patterns which would only be usable once all such patterns were located.  If a puzzle did that, and one identified three corners of a box that needed to e.g. be 4 or 7, such a disambiguation rule could preclude inferences about whether the fourth corner could be a 4 or 7.

Comment: @supercat I agree that it could make a puzzle more elegant, and I'm all in favor of rules like that (if precisely specified)! It's just that if you precisely specify them, it's not *really* using uniqueness deductions anymore.

Comment: @Deusovi: I just noticed a comment about Minesweeper; if one allows for imperfect-knowledge puzzles, but requires that players be able to prove that no move can possibly lose, situations may arise where multiple arrangements of fatal obstacles would be consistent with clues given so far, but only one could be uniquely distinguished with clues that could possibly be given but haven't been yet.

Comment: @supercat True! If the assumption is "the puzzle, with this particular information revealed, will be uniquely solvable", then that does make it possible. But I think that uniqueness assumption would have to be part of a similar "variant" ruleset, rather than assuming uniqueness "on the same level as the puzzle", if that makes sense?

Answer (score 8):

Find any integer $n$ such that $n$ is the number of solutions to this puzzle.

Comment: The solution is an integer, so there can be only 1 solution with n=1.

Comment: I probably don't get it, given that this answer received so many upvotes, but to me the answer seems incorrect. If you do *not* add the assumption that there is a unique solution, you will still find the unique solution *n=1* given that *n* is an integer (if *n* was not an integer, the answer could have also been infinity).

Answer (score 7):

I know this question has already been answered (and in a better way than I could ever have!) but I feel like it is worth bringing up the generic category of puzzle "Knowledge Puzzle" or "Induction Puzzle", which kind of fits the original description.  (This category includes problems like the "coloured hats" puzzle group, and things like [Cheryl's Birthday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheryl%27s_Birthday).)

They are "logical" (the "actors" in the puzzle are always considered perfect logicians, or the setups usually make no sense), you don't have all of the information (in fact lack of information is usually the premise of the puzzle), but the "answer" is usually the solve path, and not the end-state of the puzzle world (which is usually given to you).

In a sense, Cheryl's Birthday as presented is literally two people discussing a logic puzzle of the usual grid-kind but with (different) imperfect information and whittling down between them to one answer because they can remove option paths where there is more than one end-state.

Comment: Cheryl's Birthday was the first thing that came to my mind when I read the question! It's such an implicit assumption - that Cheryl has only one birthday - that it's sooooo easy to miss it. But the puzzle cannot be solved without it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to construct a puzzle that is:
>
> 1. Solvable if you assume there is a single unique solution
> 2. Not solvable if you do not make this assumption

How about this one:

Given a function on the natural numbers, $F: \mathbb N \Rightarrow \{0,1\}$, such that the probability that $F(n)=1$ is $2^{-n}$, find all $n$ such that $F(n)=1$.

If you assume there is a single unique solution, you'll eventually find it.  But if you allow for the possibility that there are zero or multiple solutions, you can't.

Answer (score 3):

Whereas the question has already been answered, here is a corroboration on answering it with "yes", by providing a minimalistic mathematical example. Many non-linear relations contain one or multiple points with unique characteristics or singularities, which you can exploit in such a riddle. Consider for example a parabola $y=x^2$. Find me the numerical and real value of $x$. You can't solve this unless either I provide you the numerical value of $y$, or if I provide you the given that there is a unique solution for $x$: generally, every value of $y$ returns two solutions ($x=\sqrt{y}$ and $x=-\sqrt{y}$), except for the unique case $y=0$ (the minimum), in which case $x=0$. Note that the term non-linear is crucial here. Many grid-deduction puzzles are based on linear algebra, which cannot exhibit such behavior (despite being multi-dimensional).

Answer (score 2):

I'm interested in the community's take on this trivial example using Tapa rules:

```
2 3 2
_ _ _
_ _ _
_ _ _
2 3 2
```

Basic rules force the second and fourth rows to be all shaded. For either side of the middle row, one could argue that shading that square leads to multiple solutions, but you cannot make that argument for the middle square. So there is a philosophical argument to be made that middle square is the "right" square to shade.

This of course does not obviate @Deusovi's argument at all, because once you convince yourself you cannot shade a side, you're now free to shade the other side. Just a logical observation I find interesting.

Comment: Why is the center square any different than the left/right square?

Comment: @NathanMerrill By Tapa rules you can have no 2 by 2 fully shaded. If you shade one side, then the center cannot be shaded, but the other side may or may not be, giving multiple solutions. If the center square is shaded, both sides must be shaded, giving a "unique" solution in that sub case.

Comment: The other side can't be shaded, right?  Because you can't create a loop.

Comment: Loops are OK in Tapa

Comment: You can also make the argument "If the left cell is unshaded, then there are multiple solutions, so the left cell must be shaded". Making the split in different places will lead you to different answers, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: @Deusovi I know we're quibbling about semantics, because I agree with you. But...there is a difference. On either side, whether it is shaded or unshaded, there are multiple solutions. But in the middle, unshaded leads to multiple solutions, while shaded leads to a "unique" solution. So of the six steps available to you, only one leads to a "unique" solution. So I can obviously not choose the cup of wine in front of me!

Comment: This is what I imagine would be the perfect example for this question! Basically it means that we are using uniqueness to find the *unique* move that leads to unique solution, and not by eliminating solutions which may lead to multiple solutions. For this case, shading left leads to multiple solutions, but so does unshading left. So the conclusion should be that we **cannot deduce** the state of the left cell *even with the uniqueness constraint*. Ditto for the right cell. But for the middle, shading it leads to a unique solution. So it must be it, since no other leads to unique solution.

Comment: @justhalf I recommend being careful with this example. As Deusovi points out, the puzzle does not have a unique solution, and even under the assumption that there is a unique solution, the proposed argument only constrains the "one-at-a-time" solution path, where you think of the solution in terms of atomic actions, namely assigning "shaded" or "unshaded" to a single cell at each step.

Comment: Yep! But I was looking for this kind of example when reading the question. So this answer (your explanation) is helpful for me at least =)

Comment: @justhalf Thank you for the bounty! Much appreciated, and glad you found this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> **Puzzle I:** Uisng standard set theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (i.e., the Zermelo-Frenkel axioms, including the Asiom of Choice), find a set $x_0$ such that $\phi(x_0)$ holds, where
> $$\phi(x)\equiv (\mathsf{CH}\leftrightarrow x=\emptyset). $$
> Here, $\mathsf{CH}$ is short for the continuum hypothesis.

You cannot solve this puzzle, i.e., you cannot exhibit any concrete set $x_0$ of which you can prove that $\phi(x_0)$ holds. Indeed, if you could exhibit such $x_0$, I shall take for granted that it is possible to at least decide whether $x_0$ is the empty set or not${}^1$ - otherwise I would refrain from saying that $x_0$ has been described in a sufficiently concrete way to call it a solution to the puzzle in the first place. Hence, we could ultimately prove either $\mathsf{CH}$ or its negation. But is is known that $\mathsf{CH}$ is *independent* of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, i.e., neither it nor its negation can be proved.

> **Puzzle II.** Assume that puzzle I has a unique solution. Find it.

That's easy: the empty set. And apparently the additional assumption boils down to assuming $\mathsf{CH}$.

---

${}^1$ For those arguing that my postulate that it should be decidable whether $x_0$ is empty or not is a bit handwavy, we might try to fix this at reasonable cost. Using Gödel's methods, one can certainly formalize $\psi(x)\equiv$ "there exists a proof that $x=\emptyset$ or there exists a proof that $x\ne\emptyset$". Now use $$\phi(x)\equiv (\mathsf{CH}\leftrightarrow x=\emptyset)\land \psi(x)$$ in the puzzles instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

I have a sphere with a hole drilled through the centre.  The length of this hole is 1 metre.  What is the remaining volume of the sphere.  ie. the 'Donut'

If you decide I'm honest and not sending you on a wild goose chase, then you can solve this without calculus in your head.

Comment: You can also solve it without the uniqueness assumption, but it is a lot more work.  Let the radius of the sphere be $r$.  You solve the problem with ordinary calculus and the $r$ cancels out.  The solution you are thinking of is much easier, but this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I realise now that the example given doesn't *require* uniqueness to solve the puzzle, but I'll leave the example below for those interested.

I can give an example of a Sudoku where you can use uniqueness logic to get to a solution. However, uniqueness is not the only way to get to that solution, so this is probably not pertinent to your question.

[image: an example highlighting a unique rectangle in a sudoku puzzle]

The above is taken from http://hodoku.sourceforge.net/en/tech_ur.php, which describes "unique rectangles" in sudoku. The cell R2C2 "must be" 3, as if it were not, we would have a fatal rectangle of 89s, where there are two valid placements of 8s and 9s that have no bearing on the rest of the puzzle. If it's not a 3 then there are multiple solutions. If it is a 3 then there is exactly one solution. So it must be a 3, as there must only be one solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am thinking of a number X.  Find Y such that the square of Y is X.
2. What if I tell you there is only one such Y?