# The thief, liars, and the honest

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

There are four people: A, B, C, D. One person is a thief, the thief and two other people are lying. The other person is telling the truth. Who is telling the truth?

- **A**: I am not the thief.
- **B**: D is the thief.
- **C**: B is the thief.
- **D**: I am not the thief.

Comment: Ok everyone, I think I've waited long enough, pretty much all of you were correct, so here is the answer.

A is the thief.

D is telling the truth.

B and C are lying but they are innocent.

Answer (score 33):

Even simpler solution, with no hypotheticals needed:

> B and D precisely contradict each other, so one of them must be the single truth-teller.  So the others are both liars; in particular, A is lying, so A is the thief.  Knowing that, we can easily check all the statements and see that **D is the truth-teller**.

Answer (score 10):

Simple solution.

> If A is telling the truth, then A is not the thief by A's statement. Since B and C are lying, D and B cannot be the thief by B's and C's respective statements, and thus C is the thief. However, this is a contradiction, as D also lies, and thus D is *also* the thief by D's statement. So A is not the truth-teller.
>
> Thus, A is lying, and thus A is the thief by A's statement. This means B and C are lying by their respective statements, and D is the truth-teller.

So, the answer is

> D!

Comment: There's a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 7):

> Suppose D is lying. Then D is the thief and so A and B are both telling the truth, but there can only be one truth-teller.

Therefore

> D is telling the truth.

Comment: This is a lovely simple answer.

Comment: Good point that we don't need to know who's the thief, just who is telling the truth!

Answer (score 7):

> Only the truth-teller or the thief can say "I am not the thief". Two people (A and D) said that, so those two roles are both accounted for between them. This means B and C must both be the only role that's left, liars. Since B is lying, D can't be the thief and so must be the truth-teller.

Answer (score 2):

Another line of thought:

> Setting either B or C as truth-tellers implies that both A and D are liars. However, there is only one thief and A and D are saying the same thing: "I am not a thief". If they both were indeed lying, there would be two thieves. Therefore, either A or D is telling the truth.
>  
>  If A is telling the truth, the true statements would be
>  
>  **A:** I am not the thief (the assumed truth)
>  **D:** I am the thief (ok, does not contradict with A's statement)
>  **B:** D is not the thief (invalid, contradicts with D's statement)
>  
>  If D is telling the truth, the true statements would be
>  
>  **D:** I am not the thief (the assumed truth)
>  **A:** I am the thief (ok, does not contradict with D's statement)
>  **B:** D is not the thief (ok, reinforces D's statement)
>  **C:** B is not the thief (ok, reinforces A's statement)

Therefore,

> D is telling the truth.

Answer (score 1):

?Even simpler solution:

> Maybe A is the thief. Then they're lying, so their statement is consistent, and two of the remaining three will be lying.
>  If A is the thief, then B's statement must be a lie. Fine.
>  If A is the thief, then C's statement must be a lie, in which case D must be telling the truth.
>  D's statement is consistent with all of the above, so, supposing there is a unique solution to the problem, we have found it already, and **D** is the truth-teller.

Comment: I'd call this "The Pessimist's solution"

Comment: Re "supposing there is a unique solution to the problem", see https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49557/34791

Answer (score 1):

Another line of reasoning:

> A and D cannot both be lying because that would require there to be two thiefs. One of them must therefore be the truth-teller, and the other (because they lie when they claim otherwise) must be the thief.

We can discriminate between those because in that case,

> by elimination, B and C are the (ordinary) liars, and in particular, B's claim that D is the thief is a lie.

That means

> A must be the thief, and D the honest person.

Answer (score 1):

> A and D make the same claim.  They cannot both be telling the truth (since there is only one truth-teller), and they cannot both be lying (otherwise there would be two thieves).  Thus, either A or D is the truth-teller while the other is lying.  
>  If A is telling the truth, then D must be lying.  This would imply that D is the thief.  However, B also claims that D is the thief, which would make B's statement true, and he'd be a second truth-teller.  Since there are not two truth-tellers, this situation does not work.  
>  Thus, D is the truth-teller; A is the thief (though this proof is not required); and B and C are regular liars.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution:

> A and D both say they are not the thief. Since there is only one thief, one of them must tell the truth. If A tells the truth --> D is the thief --> B is telling the truth --> 2 people tell the truth --> conflict with precondition. Therefore, D must tell the truth, and A is the thief.